# how to access the IP of an EC2 Instance in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

Similar questions have been asked before, but I could not find the exact answer to my problem...

I have a definition for an EC2 instance which needs access to its own public IP in the `UserData` section:

```
  "MyEC2Instance": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
    "Properties": {
      "SubnetId": {
        "Fn::ImportValue": {
          "Fn::Sub": "${NetworkStackName}-SubnetID"
        }
      },
      "ImageId": "ami-xxxx",
      "InstanceType": { "Ref": "InstanceTypeParameter" },
      "IamInstanceProfile": { "Ref": "MasterInstanceProfile" },
      "UserData": {
        "Fn::Base64": {
          "Fn::Join": [
            "",
            [
              "#!/bin/bash -v\n",
              " PUBLIC_IP=",
              {
                "Fn::GetAtt": ["MyEC2Instance", "PublicIp"]
              },
              " /usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f /docker-compose.yml up -d\n"
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

normally it's easy to access it via `"Fn::GetAtt": ["MyEC2Instance", "PublicIp"]`, but in this case, this throws a "circular dependency error" - sure this does make sense, but how could I solve this?

Comment: The circular dependency is probably because the IP address is only assigned _after_ the instance is launched, yet it is being reference _before_ the instance is launched.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The public ip is assigned to the EC2 instance after its creation, therefore it is not possible to render it in its userdata.
You can use [instance metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) to get the public ipv4 as well as other instance properties.

```
PUBLIC_IP=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4)
```

Comment: was curious about the used magic IP, and found that this is also working: `PUBLIC_IP=$(curl -s http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4)`